# Create multi-sites with Symfony3

Tags: symfony, multisite

I would like to create a catalogue website where some of the content (texts, images, links, galleries ...) will also be distributed on a dozen other websites.
There is a main site and several other sites that are linked to the principal by collecting part of the catalogue.

My question is that of a beginner: how can I do this with Symfony3 ?
Do I need only one or several databases ?

Comment: Look at the theming bundles like LiipThemeBundle.

Comment: Wow this looks broad. Did you research some of the architecture you could use? Honestly you could do it in a multiple of ways

Comment: Thank you for your responses. 
I'm just looking for the methods I could use but I'm lost. Can you give me some advice on that please?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to do as much symfony project as you have sites visible to users and make another symfony project. The server running this project will have to be accessed by other servers, but you should make it inaccessible from the internet.

This project will act as an API REST. It is this project that will handle the databases. It will allow your other sites to manipulate resources using routes that you can call with cURL for example.

To help you, you can use the [FOSRestBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html) bundle.